# Need help for a xpath query

Tags: xml, facebook, xpath, element, treenode

Can somebody help me formulating a xpath query please? I have this xml file containing info about post downloaded from facebook

```
 ...
<Post>
    <CreationDate>Sun Mar 20 08:20:00 CET 2016</CreationDate>
    <Id>179618821150_10154060429226151</Id>
    <Newspaper>Repubblica</Newspaper>
    <Snippet>Da Roma alle Marche. Il cammino sacro apre ai ciclisti</Snippet>
    <Text>Il ciclo-pellegrinaggio arriva anche in Italia</Text>
    <Hashtags/>
    <Likes>25</Likes>
    <Shares>167</Shares>
    <URL>http://larep.it/1Rtgs36</URL>
    <Picture/>
    <Sentiment>0</Sentiment>
    <IsIndexed>True</IsIndexed>
    <IsTokenized>False</IsTokenized>
</Post>
<Post>
    <CreationDate>Wed Mar 16 18:10:00 CET 2016</CreationDate>
    <Id>179618821150_10154051153841151</Id>
    <Newspaper>Repubblica</Newspaper>
    <Snippet>Il Dalai Lama scrive a Pannella: "Prego per te e la tua       famiglia"</Snippet>
    <Text>La commovente lettera: "Come sai, ti considero un amico personale e un inamovibile amico del popolo tibetano di lunga data. Prego per te"</Text>
    <Hashtags/>
    <Likes>25</Likes>
    <Shares>5</Shares>
    <URL>http://larep.it/1nOztp9</URL>
    <Picture/>
    <Sentiment>0</Sentiment>
    <IsIndexed>True</IsIndexed>
    <IsTokenized>False</IsTokenized>
</Post>
...
```

and i need to get all the elements named "Post" that contain an element "CreationDate" that start with some text X. How can I do it please?
I am currently using this query but it selects only CreationDate elements...

```
 /Posts/Post/CreationDate[starts-with(.,'" + someText + "')]
```

thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is almost correct, except that it returns `CreationDate` instead of `Post`. Try this way :

```
/Posts/Post[starts-with(CreationDate,'" + someText + "')]
```

Comment: Please express your thanks by upvoting and/or [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) if it's helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/Posts/Post[CreationDate[starts-with(.,'" + someText + "')]]
```